# Storm : How to pass String Array from one bolt to another?

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-storm

This is how I am emitting the data

```
collector.emit("stream", new Values(sessionid,tables));
```

Where `sessionid` and `tables` are `ArrayList<String>`

I am not sure how the bolt which will receive the data will get it as I didn't find anything to get the value in Tuple.

This is how my execute method of receiving bolt will look.

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
     ArrayList<String> keyspace = input./*What to add here*/(0);
     ArrayList<String> table = input./*What to add here*/(1);    
}
```

Alternatively, I am thinking of merging the value of the `ArrayList` in a comma separated string and pass it as a string and then split it and save it in `ArrayList` in the receiving bolt.

But, is there any clean way to pass `ArrayList` to Storm bolts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `ArrayList` without problems. You just need to use `Tuple.getValue(int)` (or `Tuple.getValueByField(String)`) and cast to the correct type:

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    ArrayList<String> keyspace = (ArrayList<String>)input.getValue(0);
    ArrayList<String> table = (ArrayList<String>)input.getValue(1);
}
```