# How to pass a String array from a Spout to a Bolt?

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-storm

In a previous question, How to pass a String array from one bolt to another ([Storm : How to pass String Array from one bolt to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881218/storm-how-to-pass-string-array-from-one-bolt-to-another)), a specific answer is given and I've copied that code w/o success for a String ArrayList, while it works for an Integer ArrayList. In the Spout, I have these declarations (each of the following pairs are used on separate runs where I comment out one or the other):

```
ArrayList<String> stringbuckets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> integerbuckets = new ArrayList<>();
```

At the end of the spout, before I emit the ArrayList, I print out the values of stringbuckets and integerbuckets and get the following

stringbuckets [Airdrop, BabyDogeArmy, BEOMGYU, CorbynWasRight, MOVEZ, TOMORROW_X_TOGETHER]

integerbuckets [1, 2, 3]

My emit statements are (one of these is commented out so only one is active at a time):

```
this.collector.emit(new Values(stringbuckets));
this.collector.emit(new Values(integerbuckets));
```

In the bolt, I print out the value of the tuple that is passed in, and what I see is the Integer ArrayList has a non-zero value in the [] section, but it is an empty list for the String ArrayList (see bold section).

tuple when a String ArrayList is emitted

tuple source: twitterSpout:3, stream: default, id: {}, **[[]]** PROC_START_TIME(sampled): null EXEC_START_TIME(sampled): null

tuple when an Integer ArrayList is emitted

tuple source: twitterSpout:3, stream: default, id: {}, **[[1, 2, 3]]** PROC_START_TIME(sampled): null EXEC_START_TIME(sampled): null

Any help in understanding why the String ArrayList is not emitted would be great!

Comment: would you be able to check in a reproducible example on github to have a look. What version of storm do you use ?

Comment: Ramachandran.A.G.: I uploaded the code to https://bitbucket.org/jimmymuth/counthashtags/src/master/. Note that I've commented out the other parts of the topology until I can get through this issue.